# Storyboard - switch tab on click

Tags: ios6, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm developing an app in iOs6 in which I'm using storyboards. I have a controller which has two buttons. When i click on the first button, i launch a tabbar controller which has 1st tab as its default tab(I haven't set it to be default tab, its all done by framework).

Now, on click of 2nd button of the controller, I wish to launch the same tabbar which I had launched earlier, but set its default tab to tab2.

I tried using setSelectedIndex method of tab bar controller, tried setting identifier to the desired tab and launching the appropriate segue. But of no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to achieve this is to have two segues from your two buttons, both pointing at the tab bar controller. You then set two different identifiers for the two segues, such as "tab1" and "tab2" and then you implement your prepareForSegue method in your base view controller as follows:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tab1"])
        ((UITabBarController*)segue.destinationViewController).selectedIndex = 0;
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tab2"])
        ((UITabBarController*)segue.destinationViewController).selectedIndex = 1;
}
```